# Entity Framework how do I nest an Expression<Func<YDTO, Y>> inside another Expression<Func<XDto, X>>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Okay so I have records to be used as DTOs

```
public record ProviderRecord(int ProviderId, string Name, DateTimeOffset InsertTimeStamp, IEnumerable<ModelRecord> models);
public record ModelRecord(int ModelId, string Name, string Version, DateTimeOffset InsertTimeStamp);
```

So I know in EF you can do an expression before the EF evaluates like so:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ProviderRecord>> GetAllProviders() => 
        await _context.Providers
            .Include(x => x.Models)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.ModelScores)
            .Select(SelectProvider)  //Works yay!
            .ToListAsync();

private Expression<Func<Provider, ProviderRecord>> SelectProvider = x => new ProviderRecord(x.ProviderId, x.Name, x.InsertTimeStamp, null);
```

However I swore I used to be able to chain expressions inside another expression like so:

```
public static Expression<Func<Provider, ProviderRecord>> SelectProvider = x => new ProviderRecord(x.ProviderId, x.Name, x.InsertTimeStamp,
        x.Models.Select(SelectModels) //Doesn't work but I want to pre evaluate?
        //x.Models.Select(y => new ModelRecord(y.ModelId, y.Name, y.Version, y.InsertTimeStamp))  //This work but it's long form inline
        //GetModelRecords(x.Models.ToList())  //Does work but I don't want this
        );

public static List<ModelRecord> GetModelRecords(List<Model> models) => models.Select(model => new ModelRecord(model.ModelId, model.Name, model.Version, model.InsertTimeStamp)).ToList();
public static Expression<Func<Model, ModelRecord>> SelectModels = y => new ModelRecord(y.ModelId, y.Name, y.Version, y.InsertTimeStamp);
```

Any EF warriors out there that know something.  I can do it inline but that is a pain for resuse and visually if I then introduce a third or fourth level of a tree.  But I may have to...

Comment: Try the `AsQueryable` trick, e.g. `x.Models.AsQueryable().Select(SelectModels)`

Comment: That did it, I forgot about how the evaluation changed at times from 2.2 to 3.1 and on.  Didn't it used to imply that previously?  Anyways thanks @IvanStoev that did it.

Comment: @djangojazz _"Didn't it used to imply that previously?"_ - no, with default settings EF Core 2 would just silently fetch everything into memory and process it client-side (which was disabled since EF Core 3).

Comment: What is someone's deal with thumbing down a question that is legit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `AsQueryable` on `x.Models`:

```cs
// ...
  x.Models.AsQueryable().Select(SelectModels)
```

If this does not work then another option is to use 3rd party library like [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit):

```cs
// ...
  x.Models.Select(x => SelectModels.Invoke(x))
```

And do not forget to call `AsExpandable` on source `IQueryable`.

Comment: Yeah 1st one is what I am using and it works but gives a possible null exception warning with the green squiggly I cannot make VS 2022 not get mad about with either ?? or ?. in different lines.  .NET 6 is so picky to point things out from the past.  It's probably fine as it's just possibility.

Comment: @djangojazz It is hard to say without seeing actual code and error. But generally for `IQueryable`'s I just use null-forgiving operator (`!`) and that's it.